# Why is 'chattr' on CentOS 6 returning 'Killed'?

Tags: centos6, chattr

Why is 'chattr' on CentOS 6 returning 'Killed'?

```
# chattr -i /usr/sbin
Killed

# file /usr/bin/chattr
/usr/bin/chattr: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linker (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not 

# uname -a
Linux nameofcompany.com 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 9 22:46:17 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Throw `strace` before that command and post anything interesting toward the end of its output.

Comment: In my recent experience, this means you're running out of VM.  Do you have any swap space configured on this machine?  How much core memory?

Comment: Thanks EEAA, MadHatter, HBrujin for your feedback/help. It appeared that the problem was directly related to running a 32-bit exe on a 64-bit system.  While I was unable to overwrite the existing exe, I copied a 64-bit version over and now all is well...

Comment: @user1038090 thanks for letting us know, if you have time you can post as your own answer to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared that the problem was directly related to running a 32-bit exe on a 64-bit system.  Problem solved by installing 64-bit version.